# Equation for bowling ball on a trampoline

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, mathematical-modeling

I'm searching for the displacement of the surface of a elastic rectangle for a given x and y and a force at a position.
Like a bowling ball on a trampoline.

The equation should include a variable for the elasticity of the surface and the position and strength of the point-shaped force.
The return should be a delta-z to any given xy-pair.

I tried a lot of sin cos stuff but could not figure it out.
One of the problems is the surface should be fixed at the edges (like a trampoline). So the influence of the force is getting weaker (or the surface is getting stiffer) near the edge.

There is no need for a physically correct model. A function that gives me roughly such a curve would help me a lot.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5):

Your problem is one of solving Laplace's equation subject to Neumann boundary conditions.  This problem is equivalent to a problem in electrostatics.  For small displacements, the height of the trampoline is equivalent to the electric potential, and the bowling ball is eqivalent to a point charge.  The fixed boundary of the trampoline is a conducting, grounded box.  You should use the method of image charges[1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_image_charges%20).  Your original charge maps into a two-dimensional lattice of image charges, as reflected in the sides of the rectangle.  The sign of the image charge alternates in a  checkerboard pattern.  To find the resulting potential, You could either sum the two-dimensional infinite series analytically, or just add up the closest charges numerically.  I think the analytical solution involves an elliptic integral, which I prefer to avoid, so if I had to do this I'd do it numerically.

Comment: The cartoon image of a bowling ball on a trampoline is quite far from a small-displacement linear approximation, but I suppose if the trampoline can handle several jumping humans then the bowling ball is light enough.  The series you suggest converges rather slowly as it stands; the elliptic integrals aren't that bad, and at least they have more rapidly converging series expansions.